# Similiar triangle inside a triangle based off of segment from feet of altitudes.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given some triangle ABC, with feet of altitudes D, E, and F, I need to show that triangle ABC is similiar to triangle AEF. 
[This is an image I made for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWZKg.png)

I have been able to show that the angles of ABC are combinations of either 1, 2, or 3 (by similiar triangles), and that 1 + 2 + 3 is 90 degrees. This triangle is also supposed to be acute. I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EFBC is a circular quadrilateral since CFB=BFC=right angle. Thus AEF=B,AFB=C, A=A.Thus similarity follows.

Comment: Im sorry I don't quite follow. How does CFB = BFC being a right angle justify EFBC being a cyclic quadrilateral?